# Robot Framework: Unable to run the Robot test case with variables that has unicode in the file

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, unicode, robotframework

When I try to run the following script I get the error:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 63: invalid start byte

Note- I have to use the same variable , so alternative locators
 But if  remove the yen symbol it works fine-` how to fix it

```
***Settings***
Library    Selenium2Library

*** Variables ***
${DC_CURRENCY_SELECTOR_VERIFY}   xpath=//label[contains(text(),' ¥ 10')] 


***Test Cases***
Test browser
    open browser    http://google.com    chrome
```

Comment: ... don't use the symbol for yen?

Comment: The file is a .robot file . And it is mandatory to use the yen

Comment: Your IDE or text editor is most likely saving the file as ANSI instead of UTF8. Check the encoding option of your IDE.

Comment: you nailed it @FlorentB. U are a champ. it worked . thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [string keywords](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/String.html#Encode%20String%20To%20Bytes) provided by Robot framework in order to encode your variable. I believe something like this will work:

```
${DC_CURRENCY_SELECTOR_VERIFY} =    Encode String To Bytes    ${DC_CURRENCY_SELECTOR_VERIFY}   ASCII    errors=ignore
```

Comment: I'm curious why you think `coding: utf-8`  would work. It's not a documented feature of robot framework to look for the encoding on the first line.

Comment: You are right. I read in the robot framework documentation about the existence of encoding options and then quickly looked it up in some robot scripts that we use at work, where this line was present on the top of the robot file but-apparently-it was there as a comment. I hadn't even noticed that in the first place. I edited my answer accordingly.